# How to register several different filters with differnt url patterns?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Spring gives opportunity to register several Filters with different url patterns like this:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> filterOne() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> regBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    regBean.setFilter(FilterOne);
    regBean.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singleton("/patternOne"));
    return regBean;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> filterTwo() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> regBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    regBean.setFilter(FilterTwo);
    regBean.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singleton("/patternTwo"));
    return regBean;
}
```

But it looks like code repeating(if i want to register a lot of filters), is it ok? If not, how can I avoid this